# Viewpager adapter loads position 0 & 1 at the same time at instantiateItem

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have an Arraylist of items that I pass to a ViewPager adapter. I am having trouble processing the data since at the adapter's

`public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position)`, 
position 0 and 1 are loaded concurrently before the ViewPager switches to the second page.

Is this typical or am i missing something ?.

The Arraylist is loaded when calling the adapter i.e ,

`mPhotoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(mPhotos, this, this);`

Comment: ViewPager has a threshold and it loads all the data upto threshold amount to create UIs in handy to help user slide / change pages without any delay.

Comment: Have you applied _setOffScreenPageLimit()_. Minimum value is _1_ for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, This is typical. `ViewPager` loads another page even though you have not swiped into the other page. As per documentation `ViewPager` require a minimum of 1 offscreen pages. That means minimum one extra page will be loaded. You can change offscreen page limit by calling this method in `ViewPager` instance :

```java
setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)
```

Comment: I wanted to set some data from the ArrayList on a textview based on the position. I opted to use onPageSelected( Viewpager's OnPageChangeListener) and that gave me the results I wanted. Thank you.